# popen for netstat is not working properly in C

Tags: c, linux

I have written a simple code for getting the netstat output in C language . But the output is NULL. When I run the command in linux terminal manually, its working .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        char HTTPS_LISTEN_STATE[500]={0};
        fp = popen("netstat -an | grep '\b443\b'","r");
        fscanf(fp,"%s", HTTPS_LISTEN_STATE);
        printf("%s\n", HTTPS_LISTEN_STATE);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Is there anything needs to be done to get the output?

Output is :

```
$ ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` inside the string:

```
fp = popen("netstat -an | grep '\\b443\\b'","r");
```

Here's the output of the program with that line fixed:

```
$ cat test.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
        FILE *fp = NULL;
        char HTTPS_LISTEN_STATE[500]={0};
        fp = popen("netstat -an | grep '\\b443\\b'","r");
        fscanf(fp,"%s", HTTPS_LISTEN_STATE);
        printf("%s\n", HTTPS_LISTEN_STATE);
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
tcp
```

Comment: Yes, Just before your answer I got the issue. Thanks for the reply